# Newman's conjecture of Partition function

Tags: nt.number-theory, modular-forms, partitions

(Sorry for my poor english....)
Let $p(n)$ be a partition function and $M$ be an integer. Newman conjectured that for each $0\leq r\leq M-1$, there are infinitely many integers $n$ such that 
\begin{equation}
p(n)\equiv r \pmod{M}.
\end{equation}
I know that Ahlgren and Boylan proved (https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2Fs00208-004-0555-9.pdf) that when $M=\ell^j$ for some prime $\ell$.

Is there a proven case except in this case? For example, $M$ is product of two distinct primes.